# WCF DTO transfer problem "Cannot convert from XX to XX"

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-4, dto

I'm having the following problem:

```
cannot convert from 'MyProject.DataLayerServiceRef.MyDTO' 
to 'WCFService.MyDTO'
```

when i'm trying to call a method from the service to add an object to the database.

The problem is that my servicereference method is given a MyProject.DataLayerServiceRef.MyDTO TYPE while the service method wants a WCFService.MyDTO TYPE

What am I doing wrong here..? I'm new to WCF and simply cannot see what I have done wrong

What I'm trying to achieve is to create a new object client-side and use my wcf service to save it to the database (I have created a EDMX file in the service).

**EDIT**

now I get a new error..:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException:
>   The server was unable to process the
>   request due to an internal error. For
>   more information about the error,
>   either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either
>   from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from
>   the  configuration
>   behavior) on the server in order to
>   send the exception information back to
>   the client, or turn on tracing as per
>   the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK
>   documentation and inspect the server
>   trace logs. Server stack trace: at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
>   reply, MessageFault fault, String
>   action, MessageVersion version,
>   FaultConverter faultConverter) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String
>   action, Boolean oneway,
>   ProxyOperationRuntime operation,
>   Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan
>   timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message) Exception rethrown at [0]: at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type) at
>   IDataLayerService.GetAnsatList() at
>   DataLayerServiceClient.GetAnsatList()
>   in
>   H:\Projekt\DataLayerServiceRef.cs:line
>   233 at
>   Projekt.Controllers.HomeController.Index()
>   in
>   H:\Projekt\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line
>   27

I've tried setting the "includeExceptionDetailInFaults", but that doesnt seem to help.. :(

The error occurs in this line of the homecontroller.cs:

```
AnsatDTO[] list = dls.GetAnsatList();
```

dls is my proxy and the GetAnsatList() method is a service method

Comment: When you add service reference it creates locally copy of each described object - so that is `WCFService.MyDTO`. What is `MyProject.DataLayerServiceRef.MyDTO`?

Comment: I've added a service reference to the project. MyProject.DataLayerServiceRef.MyDTO is the object I'm trying to send when typing dlr.Create(mydto) where dlr is the proxy and mydto is the MyDTO object.   I create the object by: MyDTO mydto = new MyDTO(); and that gets the type of MyProject.DataLayerServiceRef.MyDTO..

Comment: But where did you get `MyProject.DataLayerServiceRef.MyDTO`? Is it type used on server side for operation?

Comment: MyProject is my client application namespace    DataLayerServiceRef is the service reference and MyDTO is a public class on the service

Comment: So on my client app I have "Using MyProject.DataLayerServiceRef" and the I can create a proxy and use the public DTO's from the service.. its just that they seem to get different type's based on where I create them.. datalayerserviceref.MyDTO when on client and then WCFService.MyDTO when I use the class on the service.. and this is a problem when I have to use the DTO to transfer data via the service

Comment: @Herter: Something is wrong with your solution because you should not have both server and client side objects available. If you generate service reference it creates its own version of contracts unless you reuse server side assembly. But if you reuse it you still end up with single set of classes - you have two sets.

Comment: @Mrnka you were right.. i had 2 references to the service.. one normal ref and then the service ref.. :)

Comment: @Herter: It looks like your current error happens on client when proxy receives response message. Are you sure that your proxy is correctly generated from the service? You can also turn on WCF tracing on both client and server and check logs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: Hi again.. Thanks for your help. I've solved the problem by scrapping my service and starting over and having the new service in another solution. I think I've fiddled too much in config files and probably broke it myself.. anyway, it works now so thanks again for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by creating a new WCF service from scratch.. :)